# xcode breaks into debug mode when closing the cocos2d-x program

Tags: xcode, xcode4, cocos2d-x

I'm using the cocos2d-x 2.0 to develop my first ios game. I'm the very new guy in this area. I encountered a weird issue when playing with the template cocos2d-x program. That is, when I removed
the following codes from the HelloWorld::init(),

```
/////////////////////////////
// 2. add a menu item with "X" image, which is clicked to quit the program
//    you may modify it.

// add a "close" icon to exit the progress. it's an autorelease object
CCMenuItemImage *pCloseItem = CCMenuItemImage::create(
                                    "CloseNormal.png",
                                    "CloseSelected.png",
                                    this,
                                    menu_selector(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback) );
pCloseItem->setPosition( ccp(CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().width - 20, 20) );

// create menu, it's an autorelease object
CCMenu* pMenu = CCMenu::create(pCloseItem, NULL);
pMenu->setPosition( CCPointZero );
this->addChild(pMenu, 1);
```

and I tried to quit the game in ios simulator, the xcode breaks into the debug mode, the cursor stays in the 'glCear....' line in the following code:

```
// Draw the SCene
void CCDirector::drawScene(void)
{
    // calculate "global" dt
    calculateDeltaTime();

    //tick before glClear: issue #533
    if (! m_bPaused)
    {
       m_pScheduler->update(m_fDeltaTime);
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* to avoid flickr, nextScene MUST be here: after tick and before draw.
     XXX: Which bug is this one. It seems that it can't be reproduced with v0.9 */
    if (m_pNextScene)
    {
        setNextScene();
    }
```

and the bottom window shows:
this = (cocos2d::CCDisplayLinkDirector *)0x001dcab8

The problems persists until I put back the close menu item codes. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by quit the game in iOS simulator ?
if you actually quit the game completely, this is what's supposed to happen, so there's no bug here, this is cause you're simply exiting the game while the debugger is attached.

on a side note, the close button in cocos2d-x is completely inappropriate on iOS, you're not allowed to exit the apps like that. i'm not sure why the cocos2d-x guys are keeping it on iOS, apple doesn't approve apps that call exit().

I just noticed the question is 3 months old!, hope you didn't give up !